What's a good substitute for asari clams?
I'm Indonesian, and asari clams are really expensive here. What other clams can I use to substitute that?

In my experience, Manila clams are pretty generic clam-flavor.  I don't know what's available in Indonesia, though.

If you're preparing a Japanese dish, I believe asari is the same as what Malays call kepah or lala, which should not be too expensive?
That said, most clams taste pretty similar.  Here in Australia we use what's locally sold as ''vongole'', although that's just Italian for "clam" and typically refers to various Katelysia species.

I'll look into kepah clams. It's 1/5 the price of asari clams here. Thankyou for the answer.

Let us know how it goes, and please accept the answer if it worked for you!
